# How to add a class to the <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender /> element in a custom Gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor, admin-css

I have `InnerBlocks` which contain `ButtonBlockAppender`.

I would like to add any `className` to the `ButtonBlockAppender`

**ButtonBlockAppender [documentation](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/button-block-appender/README.md#classname) says:**

```
className
    Type: String
    Default: ""
A CSS class to be prepended to the default class of "button-block-appender".
```

**So i tried to do this like this:**

```
<InnerBlocks
    renderAppender={() => (
        <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender className={'TESTEDCLASSSTRING'} />
    )}
/>
```

Unfortunately my class is not included. Generally nothing has changed.

*The console is clear (no errors).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That documentation](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/button-block-appender/README.md#classname) is for the *base* `ButtonBlockAppender` component in the `@wordpress/block-editor` package, and that component is exported with the name `ButtonBlockerAppender` *(note the "Blocker" vs "Block")*.

But your code is actually using `InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender` which is an enhanced version of that *base* `ButtonBlockAppender` component, and as of writing, that enhanced version does not include the `className` prop — [check the source <sup>(from the last commit in April 2020)</sup>](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/3ce4265a69b0dc365f5b6268514d299b561795e4/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks/button-block-appender.js) where you can see `BaseButtonBlockAppender` is called *without* the `className` prop, and that `BaseButtonBlockAppender` is the one I've mentioned above (i.e. `ButtonBlockerAppender`).

So if you want that `className` prop, you can try one of these:

1. Clone the enhanced version (i.e. `InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender`) and include that `className` prop, but it'll be up to you on how to clone it..
2. Or don't use that enhanced version, and use the base one instead. E.g.

   ```js
   const { InnerBlocks, ButtonBlockerAppender } = wp.blockEditor;
   // or if you'd rather import:
   //import { InnerBlocks, ButtonBlockerAppender } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

   // Then in the block edit():
   <InnerBlocks
       renderAppender={() => (
           <ButtonBlockerAppender className="your-custom-class" />
       )}
   />
   ```